# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' inside spring application config xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting the error *"Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'."* when running my Spring application. I am in the process of upgrading the projects tech stack and just made the move to Spring 5 and Spring Security 5.

I have updated the application-config.xml and application-security-config.xml according to the documentation, but still get this error at runtime (there are no errors in my IDE) - I'm a bit confused - the stacktrace is noted at the very bottom for more detail.

These are the versions I am using

- Java 11
- Spring 5.0.20.RELEASE
- Spring security 5.1.13.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.3.11.FINAL

Here is my application-security-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          https://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" >
    
    <security:http
        auto-config="false"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        use-expressions="true"
        request-matcher="ant"
        disable-url-rewriting="true"
    >
        <security:headers>
            <security:hsts disabled="true"/>
            <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </security:headers>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        
        <!-- Set up URL security for specific pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/home" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/contents" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/change-password" access="hasRole('AUTH_CHANGE_PASSWORD')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/audit-log" access="hasRole('AUTH_VIEW_AUDIT_LOG')" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/support" access="hasRole('AUTH_SUPPORT')" />
        
        <!-- Fall back for any other secure/* pages - user must be authenticated -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        
        <!-- Allow anonymous access for any URLS not secured above -->
        <security:anonymous username="ANON" granted-authority="AUTH_ANON" />

        <!-- Set up concurrent session control, the logout page, and the access denied handler -->
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/public/login?expired=true" />
        </security:session-management>
        
        <security:logout logout-url="/log-out"
                         invalidate-session="true"
                         success-handler-ref="logOutSuccessHandler"
        />
        
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/public/forbidden" />
        
        <!-- Set up form login authentication, wiring up the success/and failure handlers -->
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/public/login" 
            login-processing-url="/public/security_check"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password"
        />
            
    </security:http>
    
    <bean id="defaultFirewall" class="org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall" /> 
    <security:http-firewall ref="defaultFirewall"/>
    
    <bean id="logOutSuccessHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultLogOutSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="logOutUrl" value="/public/login" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Create authentication success and failure handlers.  These override the Spring SimpleUrl*Handlers but add in extra security functionality 
    -->
    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/secure/home" />
        <property name="localeResolver" ref="localeResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/public/login?failed=true" />
        <property name="changePasswordUrl" value="/public/change-password" />
        <property name="suspendedUrl" value="/public/suspended" />
        <property name="deletedUrl" value="/public/deleted" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Set the Post Processor so that the rolePrefix is changed for the DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
     -->
    <bean class="com.amor.ngc.application.security.DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor"/>
    
    <!-- 
    When using the security namespace, Spring creates a default AccessDecisionManager (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/
    reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-access-mgr). We want to override the default rolePrefix (defaults to ROLE_), so we set up our own AccessDecisionManager
    with the default settings apart from the rolePrefix.  This is wired up to the <security:http> element above. 
    -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value="AUTH_" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <property name="expressionHandler">
                        <bean id="expressionEvaluator" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Set up the authentication manager, giving it our security service and setting up the password hashing.  We must manually create the encoder and salt source
    beans as they are required by our security service. 
    -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.Sha1DigestGenerator" />
    <bean id="saltSource" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.UsernameSaltSource" />
    
    <!-- Configure the Hydrocarbon+ password generator and password validator -->
    <bean id="passwordGenerator" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordGenerator">
        <property name="randomStringGenerator">
            <bean class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.ApacheCommonsLangRandomStringGenerator" />
        </property>
        <property name="digestGenerator" ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
        <property name="passwordValidator" ref="passwordValidator"/>
        <property name="generatedPasswordLength" value="8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="passwordValidator" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordValidator" />
</beans>
```

Here is my application-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Scan for annotated components in the codebase-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.amor" />
    
    <!-- Configure beans marked with @Configurable -->
    <context:spring-configured />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />
    
    <!-- Set up property files -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/amor/ngc/application/datasource.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:com/amor/ngc/application/mail.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Set up the post processor -->
    <bean class="com.amor.hcplus.application.core.spring.context.ApplicationContextStartupPostProcessor" />
    
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="messageSource" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.context.TypeConvertingReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60" />
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/components</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/errors</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/enums</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/data-points</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/public/change-password/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/public/forgotten-password/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/home/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/change-password/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/audit-log/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/user-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/template-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/role-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/network/delivery-points/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/network/redelivery-points/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/network/shippers/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/network/trains/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/network/flowpaths/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/reimbursable-inputs/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/reimbursable-charges/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/monthly-base-capacity-tariff/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/incremental-tranche-reduction/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/monthly-interruptible-tariff/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/monthly-commodity-charge/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/monthly-term-sheet/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/monthly-summary/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/b-factor/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/capacitybilling/down-days/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reimbursablesplit/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/daily-delivery-composition/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/monthly-delivery-composition/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/annual-delivery-composition/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/system-parameter-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/system-parameter-management/shipperReservedCapacity/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/system-parameter-management/producePriceIndex/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/system-parameter-management/systemParameterReport/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/data-point-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/annual/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/daily/dpo_reports/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/daily/rpo_reports/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/curtailments/etu-nomination/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/intra-day/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/intra-day/dpo_reports/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/intra-day/rpo_reports/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/true-up/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/true-up/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/nomination/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/log/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/allocation/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/allocation/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/nomination/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/component/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/component/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/component/quarterly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/condensate/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/condensate/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/deliveryRedelivery/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/reports/flowpath/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/allocation/event-loss/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/allocation/inventory/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/allocation/overwrite/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/allocation/monthly/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/allocation/daily/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/component-balances/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/procedures/gas-flow-adjustment/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/procedures/gfa-daily-log/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-data/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-data/dpo-gas/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-data/rpo-gas/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-data/rpo-condensate/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-data/grp-allocation-data/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-analysis/daily-gas-composition/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-analysis/two-day-gas-composition/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-analysis/contaminant-data/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-analysis/download-measurement-report/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/measurement-analysis/upload-measurement-report/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/data-management/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/ngc/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/alng/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/dpo/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/update-pig-run/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/insert-maintenance-activity/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/insert-completed-activity/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/deliveries-and-redeliveries/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/pipeline-maintenance/view-maintenance/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/support/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:com/amor/ngc/application/notifications/notifications</value>
                <value>classpath:com/amor/ngc/application/audit/auditing</value>
                <value>classpath:org/springframework/security/messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the stacktrace for more information

```
27-Apr-2023 11:48:46.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
27-Apr-2023 11:48:47.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
27-Apr-2023 11:48:49.322 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\name-of-app\WEB-INF\classes\com\name\application\application-security-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 50; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 50; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2132)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        ... 54 more
```

Comment: The order of elements in `xsi:schemaLocations` of `application-security-config.xml` is wrong. The schema name must come *before* the schema location, but in yours it is reversed (compare it with the order in `application-config.xml`, which seems to be correct) .

Comment: ahh nice i didnt even realise that - however, now im back to getting an error i had previous in the xml file - 'error downloading http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd' - any ideas ?

Comment: It matches the value as shown in one of the examples at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.4.x/samples/xml/servletapi/src/main/resources/applicationContext-security.xml, but indeed the XSD doesn't exist at that location. However, generally tools shouldn't download the XSD from that location, but instead use a local catalog. Is this an error when running Spring, or a warning in your IDE?

Comment: Looking at https://springframework.org/schema/security/, you can replace it with a version specific XSD (e.g. in your case https://springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.1.xsd)

Comment: Yeah i tried that before and just tried it again on the somehow off chance it would work but got the same runtime error as before -- i cant show/explain it all in a comment but here is a new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120867/cant-use-spring-security-version-with-spring-security-4-2-even-though-i-am-not-u

any help is appreciated