# Can't use Spring Security-version with Spring Security 4.2 even though I am not using Spring Security 4.2

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Although I am not even using Spring Security 4.2, my Spring project still seems to think it is pointing at it. I have explicitly stated what schema to use, but I still get the same runtime error.

When I try change my security-config.xml file to use only without specifying a version - http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd - it throws an error in my IDE about not being able to download the schema.

I have updated all other XML files so that they are not using Spring 5 instead of 4 since I am in the process of upgrading the projects tech stack.

Error:

```
You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema or spring-security-3.2.xsd schema or spring-security-4.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 4.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 4.2 schema. Offending resource: file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat9.0\webapps\WEB-INF\classes\com\name\application\application-security-config.xml]
```

Application-security-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.1.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          https://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd" >
    
    <security:http
        auto-config="false"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        use-expressions="true"
        request-matcher="ant"
        disable-url-rewriting="true"
    >
        <security:headers>
            <security:hsts disabled="true"/>
            <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </security:headers>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        
        <!-- Set up URL security for specific pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/home" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/help/contents" access="hasRole('AUTH_LOGIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/change-password" access="hasRole('AUTH_CHANGE_PASSWORD')" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/support" access="hasRole('AUTH_SUPPORT')" />
        
        <!-- Fall back for any other secure/* pages - user must be authenticated -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        
        <!-- Allow anonymous access for any URLS not secured above -->
        <security:anonymous username="ANON" granted-authority="AUTH_ANON" />

        <!-- Set up concurrent session control, the logout page, and the access denied handler -->
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/public/login?expired=true" />
        </security:session-management>
        
        <security:logout logout-url="/log-out"
                         invalidate-session="true"
                         success-handler-ref="logOutSuccessHandler"
        />
        
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/public/forbidden" />
        
        <!-- Set up form login authentication, wiring up the success/and failure handlers -->
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/public/login" 
            login-processing-url="/public/security_check"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password"
        />
            
    </security:http>
    
    <bean id="defaultFirewall" class="org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall" /> 
    <security:http-firewall ref="defaultFirewall"/>
    
    <bean id="logOutSuccessHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultLogOutSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="logOutUrl" value="/public/login" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Create authentication success and failure handlers.  These override the Spring SimpleUrl*Handlers but add in extra security functionality 
    -->
    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/secure/home" />
        <property name="localeResolver" ref="localeResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.spring.security.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="daoFactory" />
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/public/login?failed=true" />
        <property name="changePasswordUrl" value="/public/change-password" />
        <property name="suspendedUrl" value="/public/suspended" />
        <property name="deletedUrl" value="/public/deleted" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Set the Post Processor so that the rolePrefix is changed for the DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
     -->
    <bean class="com.amor.ngc.application.security.DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor"/>
    
    <!-- 
    When using the security namespace, Spring creates a default AccessDecisionManager (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/
    reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-access-mgr). We want to override the default rolePrefix (defaults to ROLE_), so we set up our own AccessDecisionManager
    with the default settings apart from the rolePrefix.  This is wired up to the <security:http> element above. 
    -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value="AUTH_" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <property name="expressionHandler">
                        <bean id="expressionEvaluator" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- 
    Set up the authentication manager, giving it our security service and setting up the password hashing.  We must manually create the encoder and salt source
    beans as they are required by our security service. 
    -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.Sha1DigestGenerator" />
    <bean id="saltSource" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.UsernameSaltSource" />
    
    <!-- Configure the Hydrocarbon+ password generator and password validator -->
    <bean id="passwordGenerator" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordGenerator">
        <property name="randomStringGenerator">
            <bean class="com.amor.hcplus.application.util.ApacheCommonsLangRandomStringGenerator" />
        </property>
        <property name="digestGenerator" ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
        <property name="passwordValidator" ref="passwordValidator"/>
        <property name="generatedPasswordLength" value="8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="passwordValidator" class="com.amor.hcplus.application.security.domain.password.DefaultPasswordValidator" />
</beans>
```

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.amor</groupId>
    <artifactId>ngc-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NGC Parent</name>
    <modules>
        <module>..\hydrocarbon-plus</module>
        <module>..\ngc-application</module>     
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*DBUnitTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectDirectory>src/main/java</aspectDirectory>
                    <showWeaveInfo>false</showWeaveInfo>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <showWeaveInfo>false</showWeaveInfo>
                    <Xlint>warning</Xlint>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- The oracle JDBC driver -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:EKB</url>
                    <username>EKB_USER</username>
                    <password>ekb</password>
                    <onError>continue</onError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- The oracle JDBC driver -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>5.1.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>5.1.13.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring-ws-security depends on Sun Java Streaming XML Parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        
        <!-- could only update this to 1.8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-backward-compat</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upgraded to 6.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upgraded to 5.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- removed - no longer needed to add explicitly after spring 3.2
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>    
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only able to update to 4.0.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- cant update this -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
              <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
              <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to see if it is not pulling in a different version?

Comment: Do not use quote format for error logs. Use code format for logs.

Comment: nvm its working now - I removed the explicit version and it compiles when i run on command line, just not in my IDE. strange one that ill come back to later

thanks for the help - was struggling with this one

Comment: @aled I disagree. Showing the error output as a quote block is more readable than as a code block in this case, because it is purely a textual message, not - for example - a stacktrace (in which case a code block would be more appropriate). This is why I made that change in my edit.

Comment: Quote doesn't preserve the original format, which is important for many error messages. More importantly it may hid some text sequences like HTML elements. Furthermore if we try to edit the text to get the original unfiltered text we get the `>` prefixes in every line. Code is the correct formatting for logs. Quote is good for quotation of human written text.